# Get text width in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm wanting to dynamically resize a CButton to the width of the text within it. Is there either a built-in way to do this in MFC, or a way of calculating the pixel width of some specified text (so that I can use `CWnd::SetWindowPos`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [CDC::GetTextExtent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7e878zz%28VS.80%29.aspx) to calculate the width of text in a certain font. Use [CWnd::GetDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71eseab0(VS.80).aspx) to get the Device Context from the control displaying the text.

Answer (score 8):

It's tedious.  You need to use `CWnd::GetFont()` on the button to get the font it's using, and then use the standard `GetTextText` on a `CDC` object where you will have selected that font.
It looks something like

```
CClientDC dc( &button );
CFont * pOldFont = dc.SelectObject( button.GetFont() );
 ... dc.GetTextExtent...
dc.SelectObject( pOldFont);
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @demoncodemonkey's answer, you can call [CDC::DrawText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6x7y2a4(VS.80).aspx) with the `DT_CALCRECT` flag. This way the text won't be drawn, but the CRect you pass to the function will have the width and height of the text to draw.

This is especially useful if you want to draw text with line breaks (using the `DT_WORDBREAK` flag). You won't be able to do that using `CDC::GetTextExtent`.

Comment: Is there a performance difference between `GetTextExtent` and `DrawText`?

Comment: Given how `DrawText` has to take measurements and lay out text before actually drawing it, while `GetTextExtent` only does the former, I wouldn't be surprised if there was, yes. Haven't got any empirical data to back this up, though.

Answer (score 3):

```
CClientDC hdc(this);
GetRect.SetRect(0,0,iLabelWidth,0);
//
//To get Height of Lable in advance
//
hdc.DrawText(
                TempData,
                TempData.GetLength(),
                GetRect,
                DT_CALCRECT | DT_MODIFYSTRING | DT_WORDBREAK 
            );
```