# Get GDI HFONT line height as interpreted by DrawText[Ex]

Tags: windows, winapi, fonts, gdi

**I want to know which metrics are used to calculate the correct line height** (vertical distance between the baselines of 2 adjacent lines of text). "Correct" shall arbitrarily defined as "whatever [`DrawTextW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtextw) does".

[The accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946070/how-can-i-obtain-the-line-height-of-a-gdi-hfont) appears to follow what the graph provided [in this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/string-widths-and-heights) says:

```
TEXTMETRICW.tmHeight + TEXTMETRICW.tmExternalLeading;
```

But that does not appear to be correct. Some testing with 2 pieces of text, each of which consists of 2 lines:

```
// RECT rc is more than large enough to fit any text
int HeightChinese = DrawTextW(hdc, L"中\r\n文", -1, &rc, 0);
int HeightLatin = DrawTextW(hdc, L"Latin,\r\nlatin!", -1, &rc, 0);
```

The expected return values should be `2 * <SomethingUnknown>`.

One observation is that the return value of `DrawTextW` will always match the `RECT` output if `DT_CALCRECT` were used, for all fonts that I have on my machine. So I will assume that using `DT_CALCRECT` does not provide any additional value over using the return value of `DrawTextW`.

For all fonts on my machine, these are true:

- `HeightChinese == HeightLatin`
- `LOGFONTW.lfHeight == TEXTMETRICW.tmHeight` <sup>(1)</sup>.

For *most* fonts on my machine, this is true:

- `HeightXxx == 2 * TEXTMETRICW.tmHeight`

**Which already contradicts the formula provided in the other question** (`TEXTMETRICW.tmExternalLeading` does not play a role).

For example, "Arial" with `LOGFONTW.lfHeight = 36` will have `TEXTMETRICW.tmExternalLeading = 1`, and `HeightXxx == 72` (not 74). The distance between the lines when taking a screenshot and measuing the pixels is also 72 (so it appears that the return value can be trusted).

At the same time, "Segoe UI" with `LOGFONTW.lHeight = 43` will have `TEXTMETRICW.tmExternalLeading = 0`, and `HeightXxx == 84` (not 86).

This is a list of all anomalous fonts on my system:

```
"FontName" -- "DrawText return value" vs "2 * TEXTMETRICW.tmHeight"

Ebrima -- 84 vs 86
Leelawadee UI -- 84 vs 86
Leelawadee UI Semilight -- 84 vs 86
Lucida Sans Unicode -- 96 vs 98
Malgun Gothic -- 84 vs 86
Malgun Gothic Semilight -- 84 vs 86
Microsoft Tai Le -- 80 vs 82
Microsoft YaHei -- 82 vs 84
Microsoft YaHei UI Light -- 82 vs 84
MS Gothic -- 66 vs 64
MS UI Gothic -- 66 vs 64
MS PGothic -- 66 vs 64
Nirmala UI -- 84 vs 86
Nirmala UI Semilight -- 84 vs 86
Palatino Linotype -- 84 vs 86
Segoe UI -- 84 vs 86
Segoe UI Black -- 84 vs 86
Segoe UI Historic -- 84 vs 86
Segoe UI Light -- 84 vs 86
Segoe UI Semibold -- 84 vs 86
Segoe UI Semilight -- 84 vs 86
Segoe UI Symbol -- 84 vs 86
SimSun -- 66 vs 64
NSimSun -- 66 vs 64
SimSun-ExtB -- 66 vs 64
Verdana -- 76 vs 78
Webdings -- 62 vs 64
Yu Gothic UI -- 84 vs 86
Yu Gothic UI Semibold -- 84 vs 86
Yu Gothic UI Light -- 84 vs 86
Yu Gothic UI Semilight -- 84 vs 86
MS Mincho -- 66 vs 64
MS PMincho -- 66 vs 64
Ubuntu Mono -- 62 vs 64
```

Sometimes the return value is 2 bigger, sometimes it is 2 smaller than the calculated value.

I have looked at the other values in `TEXTMETRICW`, and I've also looked at the extra data available int `OUTLINETEXTMETRICW`, but I could not find any pattern that would explain the observations.

So then, what are the correct metrics to calculate line height? I understand that I could call `DrawTextW` with `DT_CALCRECT` to get this value, but I want to understand where this information comes from (and thus, how a font designer could control it in a predictable way).

[Here is a gist with a complete Windows application that demonstrates this](https://gist.github.com/HMd38kvVVlMQEfcb/34610851057aa91a0941edbe72aa2e90). All the interesting stuff is in `WM_PAINT`. Search for `@EDIT` for some interesting code switches and breakpoints. <sup>At the time of posting this question, my GitHub account has been flagged, and the Gist is temporarily unavailable. I hope this can be resolved quickly.</sup>

<sub><sup>(1)</sup> I am using `EnumFontFamiliesEx` to enumerate all fonts, and it happens to provide `LOGFONTW` structs with *positive* `lfHeight` values. That means I am using *cell height* rather than *character height*. While *character height* is the more typical way of specifying font height, that is sort of irrelevant here, it just so happens that *cell height* is equal to `TEXTMETRICW.tmHeight`, but *character height* isn't. The relevant value for calculations is `TEXTMETRICW.tmHeight`, and not `LOGFONTW.lfHeight`.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DrawText()` only uses `TEXTMETRIC.tmExternalLeading` if the `DT_EXTERNALLEADING` flag is set when you call it - you don't seem to have taken that into account.

The line height formula is basically:

```
int iLineHeight = tm.tmHeight + ((format & DT_EXTERNALLEADING) ? tm.tmExternalLeading : 0);
```

Comment: While that is certainly very helpful to me (I swear I checked the flags - must have missed this one), it doesn't explain where the differences come from that I observe. Also interestingly then, it seems that you should basically always include this flag if you want the text to look like what the font designer intended...

Comment: I reverse engineered `DrawTextExW` with Ghidra and found the problem. What you write is correct. It appears to be a "bug" in `EnumFontFamiliesExW`. I will post a more detailed answer with some additional info.

Answer (score 3):

As Jonathan Potter pointed out, the formula `TEXTMETRICW.tmHeight` *should* have been correct, and if the `DT_EXTERNALLEADING` flag is set, then it's `TEXTMETRICW.tmHeight + TEXTMETRICW.tmExternalLeading`.

I reverse-engineered `DrawTextExW` with Ghidra and the reason the numbers were sometimes off is not `DrawTextExW` itself. `DrawTextExW` internally uses a `DT_InitDrawTextInfo`, which in turn uses `GetTextMetricsW` and calculates the line height according to the above formula.

However, consider this code to probe all fonts:

```
LOGFONTW Probe = {};
Probe.lfCharSet = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
EnumFontFamiliesExW(hdc, &Probe, InitializeFontInfo_EnumFontFamiliesCallback, NULL, 0);

static int CALLBACK InitializeFontInfo_EnumFontFamiliesCallback(const LOGFONTW *LogFont, const TEXTMETRICW *TextMetric, DWORD FontType, LPARAM lParam)
{
    FONT_INFO tmp = {};
    tmp.LogFont = *LogFont;
    tmp.TextMetric = *TextMetric;
    FontInfo.push_back(tmp);
    return 1;
}
```

Here, for the Segoe UI font, for example, `LogFont->lfHeight` will be 43.

And so, `TextMetric->tmHeight` will also be 43, which, you would think, makes sense to some degree.

**However:**

If you go ahead and select this `LogFont` into a `HDC`, and then use `GetTextMetricsW`, like so:

```
HFONT Font = CreateFontIndirectW(LogFont);
SelectObject(hdc, Font);
TEXTMETRICW TextMetric = {};
GetTextMetricsW(hdc, &TextMetric);
```

Then `TextMetric->tmHeight == 42` even though `LogFont->lfHeight == 43`.

In other words, the values provided to the `EnumFontFamiliesExW` callback for its `TEXTMETRICW` parameter cannot be trusted. Although you could argue that the bug is elsewhere, and selecting a `LogFont->lfHeight == 43` font should really also produce a `TextMetric->tmHeight == 43` text metric, but I suppose that's too much to ask. My guess is that there's a floating point conversion going on somewhere in there, and that occasionally produces a rounding error for some numbers.