# How to auto resize the text control in mfc

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to put the text in my  IDC_TEXT in MFC. I want to auto resize that control with input text. I used my code but it does not work. Could you help me resolve it?

```
CFont *m_Font1 = new CFont;
CStatic * m_Label;
m_Font1->CreatePointFont(200, "Time New Roman");
m_Label = (CStatic *)GetDlgItem(IDC_TEXT);
m_Label->SetFont(m_Font1);
m_Label->SetWindowText( _T("") );
//Display text in thread
THREADSTRUCT*    ts = (THREADSTRUCT*)param;
CDC* vDC_TXT;
vDC_TXT =ts->_this->GetDlgItem(IDC_TEXT)->GetDC();
ts->_this->GetDlgItem(IDC_TEXT)->SetWindowTextA(text.c_str());
 //Update the length-
 ts->_this->GetDlgItem(IDC_TEXT)->SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);
```

However, the number (1000,1000) is set by my hand. I want to auto change based on the text size. Could you have me to solve it?

Comment: "does not work" isn't very helpful.

Comment: That mean the text is displayed, but when the text length is large than IDC_TEXT, the other character in text will lost. That is meaning of "does not work" in my case

Comment: Long shot (I don't use MFC), does this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745693/get-text-width-in-mfc

Comment: You aren't changing the control's width anywhere, so this isn't surprising. You need to look at the link @JackWhiteIII listed above.

Comment: I saw it but they have many solution. Could you see my code and give me one good solution

Comment: I updated my solution. Let see it Nik Bougalis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

If font size is the same, and only text is different, then you should be able to reuse the old font:

```
void ChangeSize()
{
    CWnd* dlgItem = GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC1);

    if (!dlgItem)
        return;

    CString s;
    dlgItem->GetWindowText(s);

    CDC dc;
    dc.CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    dc.SelectObject(dlgItem->GetFont());

    CRect r;
    dlgItem->GetClientRect(&r);

    if (s.Find('\n') < 0)
        dc.DrawText(s, &r, DT_CALCRECT | DT_NOPREFIX | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_EDITCONTROL);
    else
        dc.DrawText(s, &r, DT_CALCRECT | DT_NOPREFIX | DT_EDITCONTROL);

    dlgItem->SetWindowPos(0, 0, 0, r.Width(), r.Height(), SWP_NOMOVE);
}
```

---

Previous answer for when font is changing:

`m_Font1` should be declared as member data and setup setup once, and created and cleaned up elsewhere. It think that's what you are doing.

Then you can draw text functions to find text size, and resize the control as follows

```
void ChangeSize()
{
    CWnd* dlgItem = GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC1);

    if (!dlgItem)
        return;

    CString s;
    dlgItem->GetWindowText(s);

    CDC dc;
    dc.CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    //or just use CClientDC dc(this) if device context is available

    dc.SelectObject(m_font);

    CRect r;
    dlgItem->GetClientRect(&r);

    if (s.Find('\n') < 0)
    {
        //change width/height for single line text
        dc.DrawText(s, &r, DT_CALCRECT | DT_NOPREFIX | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_EDITCONTROL);
    }
    else
    {
        //change height for multiple-line text
        dc.DrawText(s, &r, DT_CALCRECT | DT_NOPREFIX | DT_EDITCONTROL);
    }

    dlgItem->SetWindowPos(0, 0, 0, r.Width(), r.Height(), SWP_NOMOVE);
    dlgItem->SetFont(m_font, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank Barmak Shemirani. So, I will call your function below ts->_this->GetDlgItem(IDC_TEXT)->SetWindowTextA(text.c_str());, Is it right?

Comment: Actually it looks like you just need to change the text, and you don't need to change the font size? In that case you can just use `GetFont()` instead of creating new font. I'll update the post.

Comment: Right. I just want to change my text control to fix with input text

Comment: No, don't free or delete that pointer. It's not making any extra allocation.